# not sure on php NOT EXIST and how i should structure this function

Tags: php, mysql

I am confused on how i should structure this function, i am pretty new to php.

I am trying to get all the rows from table1 but exclude results that exist in table 2. But in Table1 it is called id, and in table2 it is called Carid.

How would i put it?

```
$result2=mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT *
     FROM CarListing
     WHERE price = '$price1'
         AND zip = '$zip1'
         AND NOT IN
             (SELECT CarListingid
              FROM CarListing2
              WHERE CarListingid = '$CarListingid1') ")
or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

In Table1 it is just called id, but in Table 2 it is called CarListingid. Wondering how would i put the CarListingid from Table2 into id from Table1 and exclude those listings that exists in both table, and echo the rest from Table 1.

Edit: after

```
zip = '$zip1' AND id NOT IN (SELECT CarListingid
                  FROM CarListing2
                  WHERE CarListingid = '$CarListingid1') ")
    or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: As long as `id` and `CarListingid` are of the same data type, you can just do `id not in (...)`.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$result2=mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT *
     FROM CarListing
     WHERE price = '$price1'
         AND zip = '$zip1'
         AND id NOT IN
             (SELECT CarListingid
              FROM CarListing2
              WHERE CarListingid = '$CarListingid1') ")
or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

you miss expr before the `NOT IN`.

see [syntax](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php)